# Index not linked properly in the navigation

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, page-numbering, indexing

I'm having troubles making Index visible in the navigation that is shown with the pdf preview of the document. Namely, the following is the end of my main .tex file:

```
% Bibliography
% =================================================================
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
% =================================================================

\printindex
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
```

This indeed show Index in the navigation, but it actually points to bibliography. Exchanging places of \printindex and \addcontentsline removes Index from the navigation. How could I achieve precise navigation to Index?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When LaTeX sees your `\addcontentsline` command, it has already finished typesetting the index. So if this is longer than one page, the reference to the page number will be wrong. Do

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\printindex
```

or try the package `tocbibind` which will add the entry automatically (also for the bibliography and, by default, the Table of Contents itself):

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % nottoc will exclude the toc
```

Alternatively you can use

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc]
```

instead of `\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex`. This will also balance the last page in the index. Remember to call `hyperref` after `imakeidx`.

Comment: @boy If I weren't the author of `imakeidx` I'd use the second: simple and effective.

Comment: \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} produce right pagenumber, but the link is made to the last chapter...